# React js router not properly route to the page through url when deployed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I deployed my react js site. but it can't load pages through url.

it can load homepage https://cekedu.netlify.app/ and when I click sign in it goes to the login page.

but I can't directly go to login page by entering url https://cekedu.netlify.app/login.

but it works in development.

import React from 'react'
import './css/typicons.min.css'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import User from './components/user'
import Header from './components/homeHeader'
import Home from './components/home'
import {Route, BrowserRouter as Router , Switch,Link} from 'react-router-dom'

```
import './index.css'
import './css/style.css'
import './css/bootstrap-grid.css'      

class App extends React.Component{    
    render(){
      return(
        <Router>          
          <Switch>
          <Route path="/login">
            <User/>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
              <Home/>
          </Route>
          </Switch>              
        </Router>
      )
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App />,document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that all paths respond with your the index.html page that your React app is used in.

For netlify, create a file named "_redirects" in the public foler and add this.

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try by using "exact" prop in Route of Home component.

`<Route exact path="/">
    <Home/>
</Route>`

Comment: I tryed this but still not working in deployed site.

Answer (score 0):

Add "exact" prop to Route which it's path is also included by another Route's path.
For example home path '/' is included in all paths so it needs to have exact keyword to differentiate it from other paths which start with '/*'.

```
<Router>          
   <Switch>
      <Route path="/login">
         <User/>
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/">
         <Home/>
      </Route>
    </Switch>              
</Router>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).